# Modify angular cli build to run custom script

Tags: javascript, angular, build-process, angular6

I have a custom node script that generates a pseudo language file, in older angular.js projects I used a gulp task to run the script as part of the build process. Is there a way to modify angular-cli to run the script on ng build/ng serve? I know I can use npm run-scripts to run it and then run the ng command but just wondering if there is a way to do with angular-cli directly?

Comment: Add a command to run gulp in package.json 'scripts' section. If you want to run it before every 'build', call it 'prebuild', and it will run first when 'build' is run.